# Is there a way to see a 'live' calculation for the code in RStudio?

Tags: r, shiny

I have a code that runs a monte carlo simulation between A/B/C, and I modified it so now it will run a MC sim between A/B/C/D. However, the code works fine with A/B/C, but if I add the D category the code just dies. It brings up the UI that it is supposed to but when I click 'compute' (action button) the program stops doing anything. it doesn't close, but it just doesn't do anything.

I am wondering if the issue isn't necessarily the code but what I am asking the code to do. An MCMC with 100k samples, 4 conditions becomes 100000^4 and things get computationally heavy very quickly.

I am hoping for a recommendation that someone may have where I can see what the R code is doing in sort of a 'live stream'. It doesn't return any errors, but I am hoping to be able to see when I add the D category the code will say 'I'm working on it, but it's taking a long time.' But I don't even know where to begin to look for something like that.

Comment: `print()` or `cat()` statements in your code?  Can you try running the program outside of your UI?

Comment: OP, you can use the ```browser()``` function anywhere in your code for debugging. It may be helpful.

Comment: As an idiomatic alternative to `print`/`cat`, I suggest different levels of logging using something like [`logger`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/logger/index.html)`::log_debug(...)` and such. That way, you control external the level of debugging messages that are printed to the console (or saved to a file). I second the notion of using `browser()` mid-code, but one problem is that it is too difficult to add new breakpoints much later in the function, and stepping through functions line-by-line can be slow going.

Comment: gdaem, I removed the [tag:rstudio] tag because this problem has to do with the R language and the `shiny` interactive architecture, nothing to do with the IDE known as RStudio. It's a minor point. Please correct me if this behaves differently inside the IDE than outside of it.

Comment: And start with small examples before running your big dataset.